# $_GET in PHP not getting utm values

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to print / echo utm_source, utm_medium and utm_campaign query values using this PHP code;

```
echo $_GET['utm_source'];
```

But strangely for some unknown reason on my server its not printing the values, when I replace utm_source to something else like test_source I am able to see the value in print.

Never faced any such issue, can anyone guide me here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php echo $_GET['utm_source']; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do a `print_r($_GET);` to see what is really in the $_GET array

Comment: I used this one as you suggested, its showing me blank white page when I use utm_source=1 in query , but when I use query=1 it shows me the array( [query] => 1 )

Comment: Maybe you should show us some more code, so we can see a little better what you are doing with this

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have no other code in file, I am running this code on test file as on production enviornment it was not working either , so I made a test file test.php and have only this code;
<?php
print_r($_GET);
?>

Comment: Well then maybe show us the HTML

Comment: @RiggsFolly before there was no other code other than the one I mentioned, but I just tried adding the default HTML code and than PHP code and saved file as php and tested and it still not working. Here is the code I have 
https://paste.ubuntu.com/23277347/

Comment: So where is the `<form>` tag and the `<input>` tag(s)?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am testing the page by directly browing the url like this;
test.com/test.php?urm_source=1

Answer (score 1):

If your site is using WPengine, you will not be able to get the utm variables (and any additional variables after the utm's) out of the URL using PHP. Some web hosts specifically target and remove these utm parameters from server requests for performance reasons. Tricky part is, utm variables are still going remain in the URL which means that you can retrieve them using Javascript instead if you need to.

**Source: WPengine article** 
https://wpengine.com/support/utm-gclid-variables-caching/

Answer (score 0):

Your original question quoted this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php $_GET['utm_source']; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

If you add an `echo` to this statement it will work

```
<?php echo $_GET['utm_source']; ?>
```

when tested using

```
test.com/test.php?utm_source=1
```

A safer piece of PHP code would be

```
<?php 
    if ( isset($_GET['utm_source']) ) {
        echo $_GET['utm_source']; 
    } else {
        echo 'the parameter utm_source is missing';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Sorry matt, on the sample code I provided you I mistakenly missed echo syntax, where as on my original file I have echo, and its still not showing

Comment: Add the extra PHP code I suggested and see if you get anything output. Oh and make sure you spell the parameter as `utm_source` and not `urm_source` on the url

Comment: I tried your code but still not showing, this is something very strange for me :( here is the snapshot.
And yes on your code there was one missing ) in 2nd line so I fixed that code
http://screencast.com/t/uooRvtzsn0a

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late. but maybe this answer helps another developer.

```
// get the value of outlink, source, campaign, medium, content

let url = new URL(window.location.href);
    let outlink = url.searchParams.get('outlink'), 
        utmSource = url.searchParams.get('utm_source'),
        utmCampaign = url.searchParams.get('utm_campaign'),
        utmMedium = url.searchParams.get('utm_medium'),
        utmContent = url.searchParams.get('utm_content');
        console.table( { outlink , utmSource, utmCampaign, 
        utmMedium,utmContent});
```